# MySQL-Inserting count into a table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a new table that contains a count for a specific column.  The column I want the count for contains different organization names.  I created a new table that contains two columns one for the count and one for the organization names.  I able to get the count to work, but I can't figure out how to insert into the table.
This is what I have currently:

```
INSERT INTO ORG_countnumber (COUNT_number, OrgLBN)
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), OrgLBN FROM ORG_NPI_HumanName_Add_Phone GROUP BY OrgLBN
as COUNT_number,
OrgLBN
AS OrgLBN
FROM ORG_NPI_HumanName_Add_Phone;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A view might work better for you.

Comment: Why not just this: `INSERT INTO ORG_countnumber (COUNT_number, OrgLBN)
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), OrgLBN FROM ORG_NPI_HumanName_Add_Phone GROUP BY OrgLBN`

Answer (score 1):

I think the first half of your query was on the right track:

```
INSERT INTO ORG_countnumber (COUNT_number, OrgLBN)
SELECT COUNT(*), OrgLBN
FROM ORG_NPI_HumanName_Add_Phone
GROUP BY OrgLBN
```

But as was suggested in the comment, a view might make more sense here:

```
CREATE VIEW orgCountView AS
SELECT COUNT(*), OrgLBN
FROM ORG_NPI_HumanName_Add_Phone
GROUP BY OrgLBN
```

The reason a view would make sense is that the counts in your table could change all the time, and therefore the data in the `ORG_countnumber` table could easily become stale.  A view would allow you to get the latest numbers without committing to a new table.

Answer (score 0):

You put the `GROUP BY` on the wrong place.

```
INSERT INTO ORG_countnumber (COUNT_number, OrgLBN)
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as COUNT_number, OrgLBN
FROM ORG_NPI_HumanName_Add_Phone
GROUP BY OrgLBN;
```